# How to connect the first responder to viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, ios6

I am developing `AVAudioplayer` in IOS6 according to my app requirement. My code is finished. I want to connect first responder to viewcontrollerXIB. But I don't know how to give the connection from first responder to `viewcontrollerXIB`. I am new to the programming. Please any body give suggestions.

```
@interface AudioViewController : 

UIViewController<AVAudioPlayerDelegate,NSURLConnectionDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UILabel *astroName; 
    IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;    
    IBOutlet UIButton *pauseButton;   
    IBOutlet UIButton *forwardButton;   
    IBOutlet UIButton *rewindButton;    
    IBOutlet UISlider *volumeSlider;   
    IBOutlet UISlider *progressSlider;   
    IBOutlet UILabel *currentTime;   
    IBOutlet UILabel *duration;
}

- (IBAction)playButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender;
- (IBAction)rewindButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender;
- (IBAction)rewindButtonReleased:(UIButton*)sender;
- (IBAction)forwardButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender;
- (IBAction)forwardButtonReleased:(UIButton*)sender;
- (IBAction)volumeSliderMoved:(UISlider*)sender;
- (IBAction)progressSliderMoved:(UISlider*)sender;

@end
```

Comment: Could you be more specific and what is the scenario where you want to use first responder.

Answer (score 1):

The **File Owner** is an instantiated, runtime object that owns the contents of your nib and it's outlets/actions when the nib is loaded.

```
If you want to connect IBOutlet connection then just Control-drag from the File's Owner to your object.  
If you want to connect IBAction connection then just Control-drag from the your object to File's Owner.
```

**First responder** is simply the first object in the responder chain that can respond to events. The responder chain is a runtime collection (or more accurately a hierarchy) of objects that can respond to an event. For example consider you have a window, with a view and on that view is a text field.

If that text field has focus it's known as the first responder in the chain. So if you send a message to the first responder it'll be sent to the text field first. If the text field can't handle the message it'll be sent to the next responder. And the next. And the next, until you get to the end of the responder chain or something has consumed the event (iirc).